# Selecting the path file for QTableWidgetItem qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm trying to get a path name to link to the image viewer but it wont link the error is on 
path = (currentDir.absoluteFilePath(item->text()) ); 
can anyone help me.
 created in qt c++

```
  void Window::open(int row, int /* column */)
     {
   QTableWidgetItem *item = filesTable->item(row, 0);


   QString path;
            path = currentDir.absoluteFilePath(item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)).toString();
             QGraphicsView* w = new QGraphicsView();
                QGraphicsScene *scn = new QGraphicsScene( w );
              w->setScene( scn );

              QPixmap pix (path);
              scn->addPixmap( pix );
              w->show();
   }
`
```

Comment: you question is not clear. Can you give details about what you re trying to do and whats happening?

Comment: I'm trying to link the current selected file to path and link that to QPixmap for it to be displayed in a new window

Comment: Now it comes up with DisplayValue is not a member of Qt

Comment: sorry.. it was suppossed to be Qt::DisplayRole not DisplayValue.. my bad

Comment: no matching function for call to QDir::absoluteFilePath(QVariant)

Comment: convert the QVariant to a string and try it.

Comment: how do you do that I'm still learning c++ I added (item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)).toString();

Comment: It still come up with no matching function for call to QDir::absoluteFilePath(QVariant)

Comment: yea ur code is wrong.. you misplaced the bracket. Im going to paste the proper code bottom. just replace that.

Comment: It now runs thank you but it still wont display the image from the path, it still opens a blank window

Comment: debug and check whats that line returning and see if the path is valid and the image exists in that path.

Comment: the images do exists because the QtableWidget finds them and displays them in a list to have the option to double click them and should open them up in a new window to be viewed

Comment: can you debug and see if the value returned is the proper path?

Comment: I found that when I click on the image it tries to look under the directory build-desktop not where the file is, is there a way of changing this to make it look in the file directory

Comment: For now.. testing purposes you can put the flie in build or project root. You can fix that later when your entire app is done? once you get the stuff working..

Comment: this is one of the last things to do the only main this I have to do is some how make it to look under the file directory not the build directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
item->text()
```

with

```
(item->data(Qt::DisplayRole)).toString();
```

and see if that works. I m not sure.

Copy this entire line and replace with urs. U misplaced the brackets thats why u were getting error.

```
path = currentDir.absoluteFilePath(( item->data(Qt::DisplayRole) ).toString());
```